# A PDF Viewer library for eclipse

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I want to include the android pdf library to an android project using eclipse and I found this solution that seems to be a good one and it is based on Pdfium an Apache licenced project.

The main problem I am facing now is that the project is under Gradle/Maven dependency controls and I want to download a jar or library project to include it to the project, is there any solution to convert a gradle dependency to jar library or something in this way?

The link of the library: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer#installation

Comment: refer http://mupdf.com/

Comment: I do not have a project based on gradle or maven so I caan't use one of the tools noticed there, is there any solution to get the android pdf viewer jar plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Google Docs API?

```
WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LinkTo);
setContentView(mWebView);
```